# Multi-dimensional array frequency count in Tensorflow API

Tags: python, tensorflow, machine-learning

OS Platform and Distribution : macOS Catalina 10.15.3

TensorFlow installed from : binary

TensorFlow version : 1.15.0

Python version: 3.7.3

We have a tensor

```
input = tf.Tensor([[1296,266,504,190,44,60,13,2,337,6742,2667,14,1,119,580,338,785,739,855,200,37,1,3,4,5,6], [1296,266,504,190,44,60,13,2,337,6742,2667,14,1,119,580,338,785,739,855,200,37,1,3,4,5,6]], shape=(2, 29), dtype=int64)
```

```
output = tf.Tensor([[0,2,1, ... 0. 0. 0.][0, 2, 1, ... 0, 0, 0]], shape=(2, 10000), dtype=float32)
```

Here 10000 is the dictionary size.

Describe the expected behavior

We want vector output such that for each index it tell the frequency of each element
ie in
`[1296 266 504 190 44 60 13 2 337 6742 2667 14 1 119 580 338 785 739 855 200 37 1 3 4 5 6]` ie we see 0 occurs 0 times , 1 occurs 2 times and so on .

Currently what we are getting is `tf.Tensor([[0. 4. 2. ... 0. 0. 0.]], shape=(1, 10000), dtype=float32)` we want of shape (2,10000)

Please tell us the right TF API transformation to do this

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
t1 = tf.ragged.constant([[1,2,3,3,5], [1,2,3,3,3,9]])

def count_values(tensor):
    return tf.math.bincount(tensor)


counts = tf.map_fn(count_values, t1)
print(counts)

#output: <tf.RaggedTensor [[0, 1, 1, 2, 0, 1], [0, 1, 1, 3, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1]]>
```

the `tf.math.bincount` counts exactly what you need.
the `tf.map_fn` takes every row from `t1` and applies the counting function on it.
Because the outputs might have different lengths, I used `tf.ragged.constant` instead of a regular `tf.constant`. Otherwise, you will get an error.

Edit:
You can also use just the regular `tf.constant` but for example, if you have two arrays like this `[1,2,3]` and `[1,2,4]` then, if you try to use the `tf.map_fn` if will produce tensors with **different shapes** and you can't do that.

Comment: its giving error ```ValueError: TypeError: object of type 'RaggedTensor' has no len()```

Comment: tf.math.bincount  (we are using TF1.15.x not TF 2.x) can only work on tensor how to make it work on raggedTensor https://www.tensorflow.org/versions/r1.15/api_docs/python/tf/math/bincount ?

Comment: Try using `counts.shape` it will give you the dimensions of the object. Avoid using `len()`.

Comment: @torniko: could you please re paste code , i am not on same page , where to use `counts.shape` ?

Comment: I do not know. I have to see your code in order to tell you on which line to use the `counts.shape`.

Comment: i am talking about your code which you provided , how to use that function you write on tensor in tf 1.15.x ?

Comment: This is for others who read this ticket , we used recently released https://blog.tensorflow.org/2020/08/introducing-tensorflow-coder-tool.html?linkId=98162087&m=1  and found our fix , super nice tool !